# Is there a more optimal way to fill in missing variables on a margin calculator?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm implementing something somewhat similar to this calculator here: https://www.omnicalculator.com/finance/margin

I have a table of items that consists of inputs for basically each of the factors in that calculator (I also have an optional tax). I have it mostly functional, but am running into some problems when it comes to filling in the blanks.

For example say we know cogs are 100 and margin is blank. Then the user inputs 200 for the total. We are able to fill in the margin at that point with this formula

```
(total - cogs) / total * 100;
```

So as of now I'm going about it like this. I have a typescript class that looks somewhat like this:

```
class Item {
  tax: number = 0;
  isTaxable: boolean = false;
  cogs: number = 0;
  margin: number = 0;
  markup: number = 0;
  total: number = 0;
  quantity: number = 1;

  ...constructor
  
  calculateMargin() {
    return (this.total - this.cogs) / this.total * 100;
  }

  ... others calculations (total, cogs, markup, tax)
}
```

And I'm filling in the blanks by writing if statements in the onChange handler like this

```
const item = new Item(props.item);

const onChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  
  setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });

  if(name === "total")
    if(cogs > 0) {
      setValues({ ...values, margin: item.calculateMargin() });
    } else if(margin > 0) {
      setValues({ ...values, cogs: item.calculateCogs() });
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to go about filling in the missing variables than writing if statements for each edge case? I know it will work, but I'm thinking there is a more simple and elegant solution to this that I'm overlooking.